# DevOps local npm ajv version has been deleted

Tags: npm, azure-devops

We have an issue with devops upstream npm feed. We built and deployed our angular app a few month ago with no issues. We are now trying to build the project but its complaining the below error. This seems to be because the locally stored version of the upstream npm package, **ajv** version 6.12.6 has been deleted; due to a retention policy. We are unable to get it back, does anyone know how we get it back?

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://tfs.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/myproject/npm/registry/ajv/-/ajv-6.12.6.tgz - Cannot find the package 'ajv' in feed 'npm_***'
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'ajv@https://tfs.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/myproject/npm/registry/ajv/-/ajv-6.12.6.tgz' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
```

The artifact view shows the below:

[image]

**Update:**

It would seem that there is no way to correct this! as mentioned here https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/deleted-versions-of-upstream-packages-cannot-be-re/1620100

Fairly poor thought on DevOps part! So currently we are now pointing to the standard npm package url (https://registry.npmjs.org/) and not the dev ops artifact one; in order to get it to build again!

Comment: Yes, it is absolutely impossible to achieve that now. There is a suggestion ticket about relax the immutability constraint, you can take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know, Azure DevOps feed has a [immutability constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/artifacts-key-concepts?view=azure-devops#immutability). So there doesn't have any way to add the same version in the true sense at this moment.

Currently available methods are:

1, Create a new feed and download the package via this feed.

2, Download the package change the package info and publish to Artifact feed(As another package.)

3, Directly use the public source.

There is a suggestion ticket about this feature in official community:

[Relax Azure Artifacts restriction on re-publishing versions](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Relax-Azure-Artifacts-restriction-on-re-/803852)

You can upvote this suggestion ticket and share your ideas in it.

Comment: Thanks for the info, appreciate the response